# Undefined reference errors when linking

Tags: c, makefile, shared-libraries, linker-errors

Linux debian 32-bit host PC. 
Project contains the source code and a pre-built toolchain, the target is ARM.  When I tried run `make` to build a firmware image, there is few `undefined reference` errors shown, compilation stopped.

```
... ...
if [ -f pppd/Makefile.cyt ]; then \
    make -C pppd -f Makefile.cyt; \
else \
    make -C pppd; \
fi
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/roleyf/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1'
make -C pppd
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/roleyf/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd'
/opt/emlix/pnx8181/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -pipe -Wall -D__linux__=1 -DHAVE_PATHS_H  -DHAVE_MMAP -I../include -I/home/roleyf/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/include  -DCHAPMS=1 -DMPPE=1 -DHAVE_CRYPT_H=1 -DUSE_CRYPT=1 -DPLUGIN -DCBCP_SUPPORT -Wl,-E -o pppd main.o magic.o fsm.o lcp.o ipcp.o upap.o chap-new.o md5.o ccp.o ecp.o auth.o options.o demand.o utils.o sys-linux.o ipxcp.o tty.o eap.o chap-md5.o md4.o chap_ms.o sha1.o pppcrypt.o cbcp.o  -ldl
auth.o: In function `check_passwd':
auth.c:(.text+0x1d00): undefined reference to `crypt'
auth.c:(.text+0x1e2c): undefined reference to `crypt'
pppcrypt.o: In function `DesDecrypt':
pppcrypt.c:(.text+0xfc): undefined reference to `encrypt'
pppcrypt.o: In function `DesEncrypt':
pppcrypt.c:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `encrypt'
pppcrypt.o: In function `DesSetkey':
pppcrypt.c:(.text+0x230): undefined reference to `setkey'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:226: recipe for target 'pppd' failed
make[4]: *** [pppd] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/roleyf/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1/pppd'
Makefile.cyt:18: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/roleyf/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source/pkgs/pppd-2.4.1'
/home/roleyf/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/Rules.mk:74: recipe for target '_subdir_pppd' failed
make[2]: *** [_subdir_pppd] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/roleyf/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router/open_source'
/home/roleyf/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/Rules.mk:74: recipe for target '_subdir_open_source' failed
make[1]: *** [_subdir_open_source] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/roleyf/test/payton_1.4.1.SR1_gpl/payton/src/router'
Rules.mk:74: recipe for target '_subdir_router' failed
make: *** [_subdir_router] Error 2
```

[Makefile](https://pastebin.com/H9ecTx6n) for 'pppd' sub-directory.  I assume this is linking error, a Makefile in pppd submodule can't find `libcrypt` library for some reason. The issue looks like an intermittent error, that occurs irregular, randomly. Sometimes compilation allowed me to build a module, but more often it doesn’t. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes it's a linking error. As the Linux manual pages for e.g. [`crypt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html) and [`encrypt` and `setkey`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/encrypt.3.html) should tell you, you need to link with the `crypt` library. Unless you have done a mistake in the configuration for the build, it needs to be brought to the attention of the project maintainer.

Comment: Your makefile is looking for /usr/include/crypt.h to determine if libcrypt is installed. Perhaps you need to install it?

Comment: strongly suggest posting the contents of the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue, problem was that Makefile have code (line 138) which was looking for libcrypt*.* libraries in the wrong place, under /usr/lib on my build PC (which have no these libs) instead of the toolchain included in the tarball. 
I modified this line:

```
ifneq ($(wildcard /usr/lib/libcrypt*.*),)
```

to

```
ifneq ($(shell find ../.. -name libcrypt*.*),)
```

After the modification, Makefile located the library and set LIBS accordingly.